# What Linux Kernel runs Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: upgrade, dell

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.3 on a Dell XPS13. When I did the upgrade from 18.04.2 to 18.04.3, I was led to believe system would be running a Linux 5 kernal. It appears that I'm still running a Linux 4 Kernel:

```
david@david-XPS-M1330:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
david@david-XPS-M1330:~$ uname -a
Linux david-XPS-M1330 4.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 6 11:12:41 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any idea's how I've screwed this up? I did a similar upgrade on Ubuntu MATE and that is running Linux 5.
Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: See:  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Standard updates to not automatically switch to the HWE stack. You need to switch manually or install from the newer images to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible because of [HardWare Enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

The [search on https://packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic-updates&section=all&arch=any&keywords=linux+image+hwe+18.04&searchon=names) gives the result:

> Package linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
>
> - bionic-updates (kernel): Generic Linux kernel image
>     **5.0.0.25.82**: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x

You can install this kernel alone with:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

or with Xorg server:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

Comment: david@david-XPS-M1330:~$ uname -a
Linux david-XPS-M1330 5.0.0-25-generic #26~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 1 13:51:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux   Suggestion worked, much appreciated, thank you.